# Find and move specific item at the top of list

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin

I have the string let's assume "lorem".

From Api I download list with items and one of them contains "lorem" as a field (title).

How I can move that item at the top of the list and don't change positions of other items?

```
 list = downloadedData.items?.map {
                        Item(
                            text = it.title,
                            onClick = Button { }
                        )
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `mutable list:`
first search `position` of lorem
then use `removeAt()` to remove that item.
Then add searched item at beginning

let item is your searched item

```
list.removeAt(position)
        list.add(0,item)
```

Comment: toMutableList().also { list ->
                        list?.forEach {
                            if(it.title == data.title){
                                val mainPosition = list.indexOf(it)
                                    list.removeAt(mainPosition)
                                    list.add(0, it)
                            }
                        }
                    }

Do you know why I get crash?

Comment: what is exception message?

Comment: Main process error RxJavaAssemblyException: assembled

Edit:
mainPosition was 0 

I needed to add
 if(mainDocumentPosition != 0)

Comment: Oh, sorry. This is not related to that portion of code.